# Syntax error on trying an example from MDN website

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I was trying out a sample code for **apply()** from Mozilla Developer Network (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)

The code I write is as below:-

```
function Person( first, last ) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}

Person.prototype.fullName = function() {
    return this.first+"; "+this.last;
};

var p1 = new Person( "Junaid", "Kirkire" );
var p2 = new Person( "Aditya", "Shanker" );

Person.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "Name " + this.first;
};

function trivialNew( constructor, ...args ) {
    var o = {};
    constructor.apply( o, ...args );
    return o;
};

var p3 = trivialNew( Person, "Junaid", "Kirkire" );
```

I am getting a SyntaxError on the line constructor.apply(). Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`...args` is not valid JavaScript syntax. It's MDN's way of saying *"This is where your arguments go"*

(So, replace that with your actual arguments)

For more information, check the MDN documentation on [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Thanks. I thought this was JS way of specifying arbitrary number of arguments. I think the code should be:-

    var p3 = trivialNew( Person, [ "Junaid", "Kirkire" ] );

and the trivialNew function should be:-

    function trivialNew( constructor, args ) {
        var o = {};
        constructor.apply( o, args );
        return o;
    };

Comment: That should work, yes. or: `trivialNew(Person, "Junaid", "Kirkire", "x", "y", "z", "etc");` and `constructor.apply(o, arguments);` ([`arguments` doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments))